# How to get access to Hanami connection instance

Tags: ruby, hanami

Hanami uses Sequel as default ORM

There are different plugins for Sequel

Sometimes to use it you need to access to database connection object

For example to use PostgreSQL advisory locking for mutexes

There are such gems for this: [sequel-advisory-locking](https://github.com/chanks/sequel-advisory-locking), [sequel-pg_advisory_lock](https://github.com/yuryroot/sequel-pg_advisory_lock)

First, you should load an extension for `Sequel::Database` instance

```rb
DB.extension(:advisory_locking)
```

Then use it in your app like this

```rb
DB.advisory_lock('my_key') do
  # do stuff with lock
end
```

But there is problem to use such libraries with Hanami

There is no information about it in official guide

On [database configuration](https://guides.hanamirb.org/v1.3/models/database-configuration/) page such info:

> Hanami models use ROM as a low-level backend. This means that you can easily use any Sequel plugins in your app. For this you need to define a `gateway` block in your model configuration, add the extension by calling `extension` on `gateway.connection` and pass the extension name in:
>
> ```rb
> # config/environment.rb
> Hanami.configure do
>   model do
>     gateway do |g|
>       g.connection.extension(:connection_validator)
>     end
>   end
> end
> ```

What I tried is define constant in this config

```
Hanami.configure do
  model do
    gateway do |g|
      DB = g.connection

      DB.extension(:connection_validator)
      DB.extension(:advisory_locking)
    end
  end
end
```

And then use this `DB` somewhere in the app, for example as `DB.advisory_lock('my_key') { do_stuff_with_lock }`

But such constants define within a block looks not good

How to get connection instance in Hanami app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is config object in Hanami -- `Hanami::Model.configuration`

In fact it is [the getter](https://github.com/hanami/model/blob/1fb18741c3c36a2db8d4269a385b99b7e9b16cf3/lib/hanami/model.rb#L62-L64) for `@configuration` instance variable

It is instance of `Hanami::Model::Configuration` and has such [instance variables](https://github.com/hanami/model/blob/1fb18741c3c36a2db8d4269a385b99b7e9b16cf3/lib/hanami/model/configuration.rb#L33-L41) like `@url`, `@entities`, `@logger` and others. So it's possible to call getters to get them

It also has `connection` method. [This method](https://github.com/hanami/model/blob/1fb18741c3c36a2db8d4269a385b99b7e9b16cf3/lib/hanami/model/configuration.rb#L57-L59) returns `gateway.connection`

And this `gateway.connection` is just what is needed. This is exactly the instance of connection to the database, on which you can call methods

For example

```
Hanami::Model.configuration.connection.advisory_lock('my_lock') do
  # do stuff with lock
end
```

I want to note that all these methods are indicated by the comment `# @api private`. It means that their implementation may be changed in future versions.